# dropping rows to a condition in a column with pandas

Tags: python, css, pandas, dataframe, browser

Im trying dropping rows to a condition in a column with pandas
here is the example:

```
df1=df.drop(df[df['Service Type']=='Bwari'].index,inplace)
df1.head(100)
```

below is the error obtained from the sample

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-13556f0da0b1> in <module>
----> 1 df1=df.drop(df(df['Service Type']=="Bwari").inplace)
      2 df1.head(100)

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use "drop" pandas is expecting you to pass it the value of a column name, not a DataFrame. Every time you see an error like this "'DataFrame' object is not callable" it means you are passing the code the wrong object argument.  For example, you should be able to do:

`df = df.drop('Service Type')`

However, this would drop the entire column, and would not be based on the condition you specified above.

I believe what you are trying to do can be accomplished with the following code:

```
df = df[df['Service Type']=='Bwari']]
```

I see you added df.head(100). If you are also looking to drop the first 100 rows, I would suggest the following code after you have redefined df:

```
df = df.iloc[100:]
```

Comment: the column name is service type and the row i want to drop under the coulm is bwari

Comment: i wanted to run it first if it is good i will set a variable name for it